# Set "type the same" in csv by python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am a beginner at python. I have file structure CSV

| year | make | model | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1997 | Acura | cl | abcd |
| 1998 | Acura | cl | abcd |
| 1999 | Elle | cl | abcd |
| 2006 | Audi | A7 | abxyz |
| 2007 | Audi | A8 | abxyz |
| 2008 | Audi | A6 | abxyz |
| 2017 | buick | casada | zzxxyy |
| 2007 | buick | casada | zzxxyy |
| 2018 | buick | casada | zzxxyy |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I will change to new_csv file: (read input csv file, and write new_csv file)

| year | make | model | text | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1997 | Acura | cl | abcd | type_0001 |
| 1998 | Acura | cl | abcd | type_0001 |
| 1999 | Elle | cl | abcd | type_0001 |
| 2006 | Audi | A7 | abxyz | type_0002 |
| 2007 | Audi | A8 | abxyz | type_0002 |
| 2008 | Audi | A6 | abxyz | type_0002 |
| 2017 | buick | casada | zzxxyy | type_0003 |
| 2007 | buick | casada | zzxxyy | type_0003 |
| 2018 | buick | casada | zzxxyy | type_0003 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have remove duplicates and set 'type'. And VLOOKUP 'type' by 'text'. But 'text' column have len() > 2000 characters. Excel VLOOKUP not match 'type'.

Please help code TUT by python. Thank you so much.

I use csv lib: I new python 7 days.

```
import csv

with open('link1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    #reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', skipinitialspace = True)
    array = []
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
        print ('------------')
        print (row[3])
        print ('++++++++++++++')
        #????
        
header = ['year','make','model','text','type']  
with open("data.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    csvwriter.writerows(array)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you found while doing research about your problem? We aren't here to write a complete code for you, we help you with some specific issue you are having in your code. Have you read [ask] if not read that article and edit your question accordingly!

Comment: Thank @Xitiz. I try find and debug. but not work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Thanks All. Code below is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem I would use Pandas instead of the csv library.

Have a look at something like this.

```
# Importing the libraries.
import pandas as pd

# Creating a Pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame([{'year': 1997, 'make': 'Acura', 'model': 'cl', 'text': 'abcd'},
               {'year': 1998, 'make': 'Acura', 'model': 'cl', 'text': 'abcd'},
               {'year': 1999, 'make': 'Elle', 'model': 'cl', 'text': 'abcd'},
               {'year': 2006, 'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A7', 'text': 'abxyz'},
               {'year': 2007, 'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A8', 'text': 'abxyz'},
               {'year': 2008, 'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A6', 'text': 'abxyz'},
               {'year': 2017, 'make': 'buick', 'model': 'casada', 'text': 'zzxxyy'},
               {'year': 2017, 'make': 'buick', 'model': 'casada', 'text': 'zzxxyy'},
               {'year': 2018, 'make': 'buick', 'model': 'casada', 'text': 'zzxxyy'}])
# Printing out our dataset.
print(df)
# Getting unique `text` values.
list_unique_text = list(df['text'].unique())
# Creating a dictionary to map the `text` values to `type` values.
dict_text_to_type_mapper = {text: 'type_{0:0>4}'.format(index + 1) for index, text in enumerate(list_unique_text)}
# Let's see what our mapper looks like.
print(dict_text_to_type_mapper)
# Let's now create a new column in our data and fill it with values.
df['type'] = df.apply(lambda row: dict_text_to_type_mapper[row['text']], axis=1)
# Here's our new DataFrame.
print(df)
```

In your case, instead of creating your DataFrame by hand, you will need to read your CSV file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV)
```

Using the code above I have transformed this data

```
    make   model    text  year
0  Acura      cl    abcd  1997
1  Acura      cl    abcd  1998
2   Elle      cl    abcd  1999
3   Audi      A7   abxyz  2006
4   Audi      A8   abxyz  2007
5   Audi      A6   abxyz  2008
6  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2017
7  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2017
8  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2018
```

into this

```
    make   model    text  year       type
0  Acura      cl    abcd  1997  type_0001
1  Acura      cl    abcd  1998  type_0001
2   Elle      cl    abcd  1999  type_0001
3   Audi      A7   abxyz  2006  type_0002
4   Audi      A8   abxyz  2007  type_0002
5   Audi      A6   abxyz  2008  type_0002
6  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2017  type_0003
7  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2017  type_0003
8  buick  casada  zzxxyy  2018  type_0003
```

Comment: Thanks George from TECH LEAD.
I'm new to python programming. I try find solution in some days. But not solution.
Again thank you so much. Your code is ok. It have note and I read easy. Hava a good day.